# Visual Studio 2010 running executable without IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to take the exe and the dependant DLLs seperately and run as an application. But when i try to do it in the development machine( invoking the exe from command line ), i see an error message saying the "application has stopped working". But it runs well in the Visual studio IDE in both debug and release modes ( F5 and Ctrl-F5 modes ). I see an error logged in Event Viewer with event-id 1000, with no useful information( Exception code: 0xc0000005 ).

Can someone help me on this? It is a native C++ application.

Thanks,
Gokul.

Comment: Ctrl+F5 is not "Release" mode.

Comment: @ Cody Gray : I meant that i am able to work in Debug (F5 and Ctrl-F5) and in Release(F5 and ctrl-F5)

Comment: Going to be difficult to say what the problem is without seeing some code. My best guess is that you're missing a dependency when you try and relocate the executables.

Comment: @Cody Gray: The code base is huge.I also think that i am misssing a dependancy. I have added the path of known dependancies. How to find the missing dependancies?

Comment: Use the fusion log: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx

Comment: are you trying to run `yourapp.vshost.exe`, instead of `yourapp.exe` ?

Comment: @SteveB : I try to run app.exe only. Infact i am not seeing a yourhost.vshost.exe in the folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I couldn't exactly understand the issue. But it works when i invoke the program from a parent directory, by just prefixing the app name with folder. But, i couldn't understand why this happens.

Gokul.

Comment: Is the application using relative paths? Or the working directory?

Comment: @Erno: The application uses Relative paths and uses some absolute paths passed in as command line arguments. But how invoking an exe can affect this behaviour?

Comment: That depends on what the relative paths are used for. E.g. when the code uses the current or working directory to append a relative path to and you start the app from a different folder than expected, the constructed path can be wrong. Does that make sense?